# Unable to Install Pip27

Tags: python, pip

I used Macport to install and select Python2.7. Python got selected but on running pip it is not detecting modules under Python2.7. By running *pip --version* it returns:

```
pip 1.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.0.1-py2.6.egg (python 2.6)
```

On running sudo port install py27-pip I get following:

```
Error: Unable to open port: couldn't change working directory to "/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/devel/gettext": no such file or directory
Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade python27 failed
```

Any help  will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run "sudo port" alone? Or just "port" without running it as superuser?

Comment: @furins  now installed PIP for Py27 but don't know how ot select it